# AngularJS model not loading data into view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am following a very basic AngularJS tutorial, found [here](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/)

I have gotten to about step 10 but nothing is being displayed in my view. What gives?

Here is the contents of index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        {{post.title}} - upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the comments of app.js:

```
angular.module('flapperNews', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
function($scope){
  $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
}]);

$scope.posts = [
  {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5},
  {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 2},
  {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 15},
  {title: 'post 4', upvotes: 9},
  {title: 'post 5', upvotes: 4}
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that you're trying to declare `$scope.posts` outside of any angular context, namely the `MainCtrl` controller.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        {{post.title}} - upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

js

```
angular.module('flapperNews', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.test = 'Hello world!';

      // We are inside a controller here:
      $scope.posts = [{
        title: 'post 1',
        upvotes: 5
      }, {
        title: 'post 2',
        upvotes: 2
      }, {
        title: 'post 3',
        upvotes: 15
      }, {
        title: 'post 4',
        upvotes: 9
      }, {
        title: 'post 5',
        upvotes: 4
      }];
    }
  ]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ybJgc3?p=preview

Comment: Damn, I thought it existed in a global context. This worked and I'll accept in seven minutes

Comment: Angular actually tries to prevent you from creating anything within a global context. The global namespace should be kept clear and anything you need to access in other components should be injected.